# Creating and writing to file - Python

Tags: python, file, createfile, writetofile

I want to create a file with a name according to a variable. That is my first problem and then I want to write what is printed to the screen in console to that file.

This is what I have, I am currently getting an error at the .open. - 'EOL while scanning string literal'. However I guess there will be more errors to follow that.

```
saveFile.open((fileName)".txt,'w')
saveFile.write("Final Quote Price: £", format(FinalPrice, '.2f'), "Plus VAT")
saveFile.close()
```

I just put an example in the .write part but I want it to write certain parts of what is printed to the screen in console to file - is that possible?

Comment: Anybody know how to define the saveFile?

Answer (score 0):

i think u missed a `+` between your variable and string literal.
`saveFile.open((fileName)+".txt,'w')`

Answer (score 0):

There are missing quotes:

```
saveFile = open(fileName+".txt",'w')
saveFile.write("Final Quote Price: £{:.2f} Plus VAT".format(FinalPrice))
saveFile.close()
```

Comment: Thank you, my problem now is saveFile is not properly defined, how do I do that?

Comment: perhaps you want to define `saveFile` as the return value of the standard `open` function.

Answer (score 0):

```
saveFile.open(fileName + ".txt",'w')
saveFile.write("Final Quote Price: £" + format(FinalPrice, '.2f') + "Plus VAT")
saveFile.close()
```

This should work

Answer (score 0):

There is a double quota lost in your code, try this,

```
saveFile.open((fileName)+".txt",'w')
saveFile.write("Final Quote Price: £", format(FinalPrice, '.2f'), "Plus VAT")
saveFile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

To write and to read date from a file with a variable name:

```
fileName = 'fileData'
finalPrice = 12.003321

fileObj = open(fileName + ".txt", 'w')
fileObj.write("Final Quote Price: £" + format(finalPrice, '.2f') + "Plus VAT")
fileObj.close()

with open(fileName + '.txt', 'r') as file:
    fileString = file.read()
    print("Line: " + fileString)
```